# SUBQUERIES in SQL with 2 relation 1:n

Tags: mysql, subquery

I'am new in SQL and I have this relational model:

I will mark primary keys with * and foreign keys with -

```
Client(id*,name)

Site(id*,name,addrees,idClient-)

Device(id*,serialnumeber,idSite-)
```

From these tables I want a new table to be like this:

```
*client.name*,*numberofsites*,*numerberofdevices*(total, every site grouped together).
```

I tried this but doesn't work:

```
SELECT sq.*, count(Devices.id) 
from (
       SELECT Clients.id,Clients.name,Clients.notes,count   (Sites.id),Sites.ids         
       FROM Clients 
          left join Sites on Clients.id=Sites.id Cliente 
       group by Clients.id) as sq 
left join Devices on Devices.idSites=sq.Sites.id 
group by sq.Sites.id
```

Comment: Format your code properly.

Comment: Help us help you.  "I tried this but doesn't work".  Doesn't work how???  error out???  blank result???  wrong result???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
select c.Name ClientName,
       count(distinct s.id) NumberOfSites,
       count(distinct d.id) NumerberOfDevices
from Client c
join Site s on c.id = s.idClient
join Device d on s.id = d.idSite
group by c.Name
```

Comment: This won't work on a MySQL server with enabled `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`sql_mode.. The problem is you can't mix a non-aggregate column with aggregate functions without a `GROUP BY` clause.. Every SQL standard database would reject this query.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Yes, I forgot about `group by`. Edited answer

Comment: The `DISTINCT` option in the `COUNT` is there to "nullify" (neutralize) the multiplying effect which can be caused by the joining one-to-many relations i assume?

Comment: @RaymondNijland Yes :) Client 1-n Site, Site 1-n Device, so in turn Client 1-n Device

Comment: i always rewritten delivered tables with count approach to "nullify" (neutralize) the multiplying effect.. But i know what `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)` does so i recognized it's goal.. i only believe the delivered tables approach would scale much better on larger number of records because `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)` looks to be running on all records caused by the JOIN one-to-many multiplying product.

Comment: love you, it worked but i still can't figure out how the query works.